# Google Apps Script Obtain Physical Location

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

With Google Apps Script, how do you return the current user's physical location?

Comment: I don't actually know the answer to this question but the [Class User](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/user) only has one method and it is getEmail().  So my guess is that you can't get their physical location.  But I'll be returning to see what others are saying.

Comment: That's what I was seeing and I couldn't find any information about obtaining location. The app I have basically has a bunch of input boxes and one being the location they are at. Would like, if possible, to have a script (even plain javascript if possible) so they can simply click a button to auto-add where they are at.

Comment: There is a method named `getActiveUserLocale()` but the method name is misleading.  It doesn't get the users location.  It "Gets the language setting of the current user as a two-letter string — for example, en for English"  [Link to Apps Script Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/session#getActiveUserLocale())

Comment: There is an HTML5 Geolocation API: [Link to information - Geolocation](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp)  I haven't tried using it in a Web App, dialog box, or sidebar.

Comment: Also see:  [Developers.google.com](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/native-hardware/user-location/)

Comment: If your running your code as a web app hosted somewhere other than Google then you can certainly get their IP Address with PHP this is how I do it on my website. `<?php $ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; echo('<br />Your IP is '.$ip); ?>` and that can often resolve to a physical location with the help of http://freegeoip.net/

Comment: Sadly, it will only be with GAS so it can't use php and if the HTML5 Geolocation API works, it only returns the user's coordinates - is there a way to convert it within the page to an actual address?

Comment: Geo Location Services normally work both ways.  Read their API.

Comment: Just made some attempts with the Geolocation w/ google's API and the console shows the request has been blocked as is not being delivered over https (guessing even though the page is https, the actual data is via iFrame and it won't allow it).

Comment: How accurate do you need the location to be? If you're just looking for a city, you could possibly look in the user's sent email to pull out the IP address that the emails were sent from and do a lookup on the IP address to get the city. This won't provide the most accurate results but if you're only looking for success in the average case it might work.